# Android SDK's adb: 32bit or 64? hello-world failure

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying the simplest of the tasks, which is the "hello world" tutorial of Android Studio. I'm on a 32bit Ubuntu (14.04) and I downloaded Android Studio today.
I got blocked when I try to run it, since adb isn't responding:

> com.android.ddmlib - Unable to detect adb version, adb output: /home/me/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: 1:  /home/me/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: Syntax error: ")" unexpected

When I tried to run adb by hand I discovered that it's not 32 bit while I'm on a 32 bit platform. "file adb" returns:

> adb: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=[something], not stripped.

Did I miss some step where I could have picked the platform? Everyone seems to have the opposite problem, platform 64bit vs. file 32bit.

Comment: @AlexP. Yes I think it's the same. I didn't find it before.

Answer (score 2):

The [official site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other) give you a download binary that should configure and setup the required adb on your system, but i am guessing it is still setting up x64 version of adb on your system.

Since the site in itself doesnot list the x86 version, you have to look into the [archived](http://developer.android.com/sdk/older_releases.html) section. Do the following

1. Download the x86 version for Linux platform and install it.
2. Update your .bash_profile with the exported path pointing to the new location of adb.
3. Restart terminal and use adb.

Comment: That's a possibility, thanks. I believe the tag "duplicate" is better though.